# Header file is included, but still undefined reference

Tags: c

I have simplified the code to the minimum

```
#include "frozen.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *json = "{ \"a\": 123, \"b\": \"hi\", c: true }";

    int value = 0;
    json_scanf(json, strlen(json), "{c: %B}", &value);

    printf("Hello World\n");
    // assert( json != NULL );
    printf( "json: %s\n", json );
    printf( "json.c: %s\n", value );
    // free( json );

    return 0;
}
```

directory structure:

- /home/projects/json-test/main.c
- /home/projects/json-test/frozen/{contents of https://github.com/cesanta/frozen repo}

What I do:

1. `gcc main.c -Ifrozen -o main`

What is being displayed in output:

```
main /tmp/ccsYWNAP.o: In function `main': main.c:(.text+0x43):
undefined reference to `json_scanf' collect2: error: ld returned 1
exit status
```

I have very limited knowledge in C, thus I may be missing some steps, so take into account that I literally did not do anything else than written above, maybe I should have. I am used to loosely typed php/js/python kind of languages, but I was reading that just including file does not tell gcc that "you should search for json_scanf inside frozen.h". Should there be some sort of a "glue", or "linking" step I am missing?

UPDATE: Based on responses, I have created this `Makefile`:

```
CC = gcc
FLAGS = -std=c99
DEST_DIR = ./bin
DEST_PATH = "$(DEST_DIR)/main"
BUILD_DIR = ./build


all: clean directories json main.o
    $(CC) $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o -o $(DEST_PATH) $(FLAGS)

main.o: src/main.c $(BUILD_DIR)/frozen.o
    $(CC) src/main.c -c -o $(BUILD_DIR)/main.o $(FLAGS)

json: json.o


json.o: src/frozen/frozen.c src/frozen/frozen.h
    $(CC) src/frozen/frozen.c -c -o $(BUILD_DIR)/frozen.o $(FLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)

directories:
    mkdir -p $(DEST_DIR)/
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)/
```

And changing `#include "frozen.h"` to `#include "frozen/frozen.h"`, and running `make`, creates `build/main` file that can be successfully ran with `./bin/main` command. Thank you!

Comment: Try using the #include with directory like ```#include "frozen/frozen.h"```

Comment: Probably you didn't link the actual library to the project. `-I` only adds an additional include path. Try `gcc main.c frozen.c -Ifrozen -o main`

Comment: @Xosrov already tried, did not help, that was my first way to do stuff

Comment: @Lundin yes, that did the trick, but with full path `gcc main.c frozen/frozen.c -Ifrozen -o main`. Can you please write proper answer to my question, and extend on how to do that properly (makefile?) so that I don't need to append path to every single headerfile I am planning to use?

Comment: This looks like a linker error. It doesn't seem that you have compiled frozen and linked that with your main.

Comment: In my opinion you should build this lib to object file `gcc src/frozen/frozen.c -c -o build/frozen.o` Same you main.c file. And next build all object files: `gcc build/*.o -o bin/exec $(FLAGS)`. Ofcourse in pretty makefile :)

Comment: @IgorGalczak okay, I have been reading many makefiles but I can't seem to find common design practice. Could you please demonstrate what such a makefile would look like? Or, at very least, link to some good quality manual for doing that?

Comment: @Deele Ofcourse there is my Makefile from hobby project: http://galczak.it/Makefile
Warning about indent: there must are tabs. But for big project i recommend cmake, try Clion and CmakeList.txt

Comment: @IgorGalczak wow, nice. You are using json too. Would you recommend something else than "frozen" for working with json formatted output? I essentially need this as replacement for currently used API response generation that is basically concatenated string.

Comment: @Deele I writting my own library to parse json, because i didnt find nothing light, speed and secure, i would show you but not done yet.

Comment: @IgorGalczak inspired by your makefile, I made my own, look at my updated post, and comment if you can :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugh. You don't have a mistake. The library developer has some really bad coding practices. Basically, for whatever reason, his header is not sufficient for compilation. If you look at the `unit_test.c` in the repository of frozen, you will see he's actually including `frozen.c` instead of `frozen.h`. If you change your `#include "frozen.h"` to `#include "frozen.c"` it will work fine. The other option is to provide the `.c` file explicitly:

`gcc frozen/frozen.c main.c -Ifrozen`

Normally, you'd put everything in the header, or require the library to be compiled, as a .a file and then linked when you use it, but he hasn't provided a makefile that does that.

EDIT: You can also compile `frozen.o` beforehand, but the library's author should've really provided a makefile to do that...

```
gcc -c frozen.c -o ../frozen.o
cd ..
gcc main.c frozen.o -Ifrozen
```

Comment: *"his header is not sufficient for compilation"* How? It seems to me to include only declarations, which is how it's supposed to be. *"If you change your #include "frozen.h" to #include "frozen.c" it will work fine"* That is not good way to do it. *"The other option is to provide the .c file explicitly:"* That is the correct way. *"Normally, you'd put everything in the header"* That applies only a limited set of libraries, because it can come with some problems. It's not good general advice.

Comment: @user694733 if I were to be providing a library, I'd expect a .h file only (Which has a number of advantages) or a makefile that produces a `.o`/`.so`/`.a` so the library can be compiled and then linked. The author of the library has provided neither and in fact when compiling his tests, he himself includes `frozen.c` instead of `frozen.h`. If the library's author has done it that way, I don't see why the user shouldn't do it in the same manner.

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu Thank you for your insights. Could you please add some sort of a simple makefile template that would do all of that?

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu if I complie `frozen.o`, how do I avoid adding everything related to that library inside compilation path? If I would have 10 vendor libraries in this file used, would that mean that the command to compile main.c would grow 10 times bigger accordingly?

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu No need `-Ifrozen ` in `gcc main.c frozen.o -Ifrozen`

Comment: *"makefile that produces a .o/.so/.a so the library can be compiled and then linked."* For these kind of single module embedded libraries this is fairly normal. There are so many different toolchains that providing makefile can be difficult. *"If the library's author has done it that way,"* Library unit tests are a bit of a special case, because it allows author to test library parts that have internal linkage or other internal functionality. Usually user has no need for these, and these symbols are only serve to pollute their namespace.

Comment: @user694733 thank you for the explanation. I mostly use C++ these days and my libraries are all header only, so that users can use templates with them. In C world, obviously that's not a concern, and it might be annoying to write a Makefile that does all of it, but cmake or ninja or any of those are supposed to solve this problem..

Comment: @Deele, in general that's what happens in C++ compilation. If you have 10 libraries that are being linked, your gcc command will grow quite a bit. This is why people rely on build systems such as CMake which take care of the long compilation commands. I will hack up some Makefile later tonight for you. EDIT: I see you already have a Makefile that does the job for you